# View Locked Liquidity expiration date

Tags: node.js, ethereum, binance, ethers.js

We can see the liquidity lock expiration date using bscscan.com / etherscan.io, but how do we do this programmatically?

Step 1) [View of the LP token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMGAd.png)

Step 2) [View of Lock event happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlwBb.png)

Step 3) [Lock event contains unlockDate parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1mBg.png)

Tokensniffer.com is able to query this somehow: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnvm7.png)

How can I view that unlockDate timestamp like tokensniffer did?

Comment: Instead of linking to images (which may not work for everyone, or may disappear & render the question incomprehensible down the road), embed the images and provide context. Remember, what you ask isn't just for you, but also for anyone else trying to figure it out after you.

Comment: Hello @omegaelite, I have the same question. Have you found some kind of answer ?